# Why is my reaction role command not giving people roles?

Tags: python, discord.py

My reaction role command that I made sends the message and adds the role, but when someone clicks it, it doesn't do anything, and there isn't any errors in my terminal. Can someone help me?

```
@client.command(description="Use reactions to give people roles.", aliases=['rr', 'reactionrole'])
async def reactrole(ctx, emoji, role : discord.Role, *, message):
    message = await ctx.send(message)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)

    with open('reactrole.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

        new_react_role = {
            'role_name':role.name,
            'role_id':role.id,
            'emoji':emoji,
            'message_id':message.id
        }

        data.append(new_react_role)


    with open('reactrole.json', 'w') as j:
        json.dump(data, j, indent=4)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    if payload.member.bot:
        pass

    else:

        with open('reactrole.json') as react_file:

            data = json.load(react_file)
            for x in data:
                if x['emoji'] == payload.emoji.name and x['message_id'] == payload.message_id:
                    role = discord.utils.get(client.get_guild(payload.guild_id).roles, id=x['role_id'])

                    await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Do you have `discord.Intents.reactions` enabled?

Comment: I don't know. How do I enable it @itzFlubby

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `discord.Intents.reactions`. This can be achieved by setting this attribute at the declaration of your `client` object.

---

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.reactions = True

client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
```

Comment: I did that, restarted my bot, and it still won't work.

Comment: Do a `print` right below your `else:`. Does it show?

Comment: No, it doesn't print the message @itzFlubby